# Getting "Could not load file or assembly" in .net core 3.1 app while file is there with right public token key

Tags: c#, .net-core

I know there are many questions like this on stackoverflow, but I was not able to find relevant to my situation. I have Azure Functions App built on .Net Core 3.1, with reference to System.Text.Json and System.Text.Encodings.Web of ver 6.0.0

When I run it with "Debug" I got

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

If I run

```
([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile("C:\DEV\prj\src\My.Functions\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\system.text.encodings.web.dll")).FullName
```

I got exactly that `'System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'`

Right name, right public key.

Solution rebuild and VS restart did not help

PROJ file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>My.Functions</RootNamespace>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" Version="3.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Architect.Identities.Azure" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake" Version="12.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Data.Tables" Version="12.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: `'System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=6.0.0.0` ??? Shouldn't you be targeting .NET (Core) 6 instead? Did you use an Azure Functions version that uses the .NET 6 runtime?

Comment: we uses the latest LTS, .net 6 has just been released, have not got a chance to migrate whole solution to it. It should work with .net core 3.1 too

Comment: .NET 6 **is** the latest LTS. If you want to target .NET Core 3.1 you should configure your Azure Function to use it explicitly

Comment: If you target Azure Functions 4, the default is to use NET 6. If you want to keep using .NET Core 3.1 you should use Azure Functions 3. Check the [Azure Functions runtime versions overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Comment: We target Azure Functions v3, not 4

Comment: Your application is looking for a .NET 6 assembly. That's what `'System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=6.0.0.0,` says. Perhaps you changed the target runtime, or perhaps you upgraded some Microsoft.Extensions.* or packages to the latest major version which *is* 6. BTW you could switch to Functions 4 and get a .NET 6 runtime

Comment: Put the relevant information in the question itself. Functions version, project target version, NuGet package versions. Posting the full `csproj` wouldn't hurt. Something in there is looking for a .NET 6 assembly. Perhaps it's a direct package reference, or an indirect dependency to the latest major version without an upper limit. Or perhaps a too lenient `Version` constraint

Comment: I added whole project file to to the question description. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In my case problem was solved by adding to project file following xml

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <FunctionsPreservedDependencies Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: this also worked for me when I couldn't get the file to deploy when publishing. Must remember this one.